Timeout error when uploading PDF and CSV files in Django app on o2switch server
I deployed a Django application on an o2switch server and I am trying to upload files to my media folder. My code works perfectly for .txt and .xlsx files, but it does not work for .pdf or .csv files. I get a timeout error, and it seems that the request does not even reach the server, because nothing appears in the logs.
I tried to do a test with a PHP script on the same domain, and it works for all file types. So the problem seems to come either from the Django Rest Framework application, or from a specific configuration on o2switch.
As a reminder, uploads work fine with .txt files, but I get a timeout for .pdf and .csv files. Do you have any ideas on what could cause this behavior? Is it a problem related to Django Rest Framework or to the o2switch configuration? Or python 3.8.18?
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Back_end_Gaz_elec.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()
class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME
        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)

My static and media file configuration in settings.py

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

and my urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('application.urls')),
    path('api-dashboard/', include('admin_dashboard.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Here are some more details:
Django==4.0.3
django-cleanup==6.0.0
django-cors-headers==3.11.0
django-environ==0.11.2
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.1.0


# settings.py
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10485760  # 10 MB
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10485760  # 10 MB


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
